# How to make my input dynamic between tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using setstate to change dynamicaly the name of the tabs with the ' nom du client ' but not working as expected. All the inputs of all tabs are changing event when i create a new one. Does anyone have an idea please ?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import uuid from 'uuid';

import './tab.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tabs: [
      {id: 1, name: '', content: 'Ceci est le premier devis !'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Devis 2', content: "Regardes ! C'est le deuxieme devis"},
    ],
    currentTab: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Devis 1',
      content: 'Ceci est le premier devis !',
    },
    editMode: false,
    editTabNameMode: false,
  };

  handleDoubleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      editTabNameMode: true,
    });
  };

  handleEditTabName = e => {
    const {currentTab, tabs} = this.state;

    const updatedTabs = tabs.map(tab => {
      if (tab.id === currentTab.id) {
        return {
          ...tab,
          name: e.target.value,
        };
      } else {
        return tab;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      tabs: updatedTabs,
      currentTab: {
        ...currentTab,
        name: e.target.value,
      },
    });
  };

  handleOnBlur = () => {
    this.setState({
      editTabNameMode: false,
    });
  };

  createTabs = () => {
    const {tabs, currentTab, editTabNameMode} = this.state;

    const allTabs = tabs.map(tab => {
      return (
        <li>
          {editTabNameMode && currentTab.id === tab.id ? (
            <input
              value={tab.name}
              onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
              onChange={this.handleEditTabName}
            />
          ) : (
            <button
              className={currentTab.id === tab.id ? 'tab active' : 'tab'}
              onClick={() => this.handleSelectTab(tab)}
              onDoubleClick={() => this.handleDoubleClick(tab)}
            >
              {tab.name}
            </button>
          )}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return <ul className="nav nav-tabs">{allTabs}</ul>;
  };

  handleSelectTab = tab => {
    this.setState({
      currentTab: tab,
      editMode: false,
      editTabNameMode: false,
    });
  };

  handleAddTab = () => {
    const {tabs} = this.state;

    const newTabObject = {
      id: uuid(),
      name: `Devis ${tabs.length + 1}`,
      content: `Devis en cours `,
    };

    this.setState({
      tabs: [...tabs, newTabObject],
      currentTab: newTabObject,
      editMode: false,
      editTabNameMode: false,
    });
  };

  handleDeleteTab = tabToDelete => {
    const {tabs} = this.state;
    const tabToDeleteIndex = tabs.findIndex(tab => tab.id === tabToDelete.id);

    const updatedTabs = tabs.filter((tab, index) => {
      return index !== tabToDeleteIndex;
    });

    const previousTab =
      tabs[tabToDeleteIndex - 1] || tabs[tabToDeleteIndex + 1] || {};

    this.setState({
      tabs: updatedTabs,
      editMode: false,
      editTabNameMode: false,
      currentTab: previousTab,
    });
  };

  setEditMode = () => {
    this.setState({
      editMode: !this.state.editMode,
    });
  };
```

Here is my function to change the title of the tab

```
  handleChangeTitle = e => {
    const {currentTab, tabs} = this.state;

    const updateTitle = tabs.map(tab => {
      if (tab.id === currentTab.id) {
        return {
          ...currentTab,
          name: e.target.value,
        };
      } else {
        return tab;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      tabs: updateTitle,
      currentTab: {
        ...currentTab,
        name: e.target.value,
      },
    });
  };
```

And the rest of my component

```
  handleContentChange = e => {
    const {tabs, currentTab} = this.state;

    const updatedTabs = tabs.map(tab => {
      if (tab.name === currentTab.name) {
        return {
          ...tab,
          content: e.target.value,
        };
      } else {
        return tab;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      tabs: updatedTabs,
      currentTab: {
        ...currentTab,
        content: e.target.value,
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {currentTab, editMode} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="well">
          <button className="add-tab-button" onClick={this.handleAddTab}>
            Creer un devis
          </button>
          {this.createTabs()}
          <div className="tab-content">
            <div>
              <p>Nom du client</p>
```

Here is my input

```
              <input onChange={this.handleChangeTitle} type="text"></input>
            </div>
            {editMode ? (
              <div>
                <textarea
                  onChange={this.handleContentChange}
                  value={this.state.currentTab.content}
                />
                <button className="save-button" onClick={this.setEditMode}>
                  Done
                </button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <p>{currentTab.content}</p>

                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="lol" />

                {currentTab.id ? (
                  <div
                    style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}
                  >
                    <button
                      className="edit-mode-button"
                      onClick={this.setEditMode}
                    >
                      Editer le devis
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteTab(currentTab)}>
                      Supprimer le devis
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ''
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Btw im new to React, if you need more details or something feel free to ask